# Laravel eloquent firstOrCreate interval of dates

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a way to use firstOrCreate with an interval of dates. I know you can use:

```
Model::firstOrCreate(['field' => $value], ['created_at' => $dateValue]);
```

But is it possible to check if the record exist between the last few days?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source for `firstOrCreate`, all it does to check the conditions is pass it to `where()`:

```
if (! is_null($instance = $this->where($attributes)->first())) {
    return $instance;
}
```

Meaning you could use anything that could be passed to `where`, which includes an array of arguments:

```
Model::firstOrCreate([
    ['date', '>', $start],
    ['date', '<', $end]
], ['created_at' => $dateValue]);
```

Comment: I tried the solution but got a new Model every time. This is what I did: 
$start = "18-04-01 4:41:51";
   $end = "18-04-01 22:41:51";
Model::firstOrCreate([
            ['created_at', '>', $start], 
            ['created_at', '<', $end], 
            'name' => $name, 
            'field' => value
        ]);

Comment: @J.Avalos are you trying to check the dates, then create one with name and field?  Or are you also trying to check for one with that current name? your commented code is looking for one with all of those values already, you missed a `]`.  This function requires 2 arguments.